# python3 unit testing, patching return of instance method not working

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest, uuid

I am trying to do the following:

```
@patch('uuid.uuid4', autospec=True)
def test_generate_adid(self, patched_uuid, app_api):
    patched_uuid.return_value = "9e51ab81-6d65-4b81-af3b-8f7f49d69ba7"
    adid = app_api.generate_adid()
    assert adid == "9e51ab81-6d65-4b81-af3b-8f7f49d69ba7"
```

Where `app_api` is a fixture of the class under test.

However, in my `app_api` class, `uuid4()` is not getting patched and keeps returning a uuid other than the one I am trying to force. Here is what the `generate_adid()` instance method looks like:

```
from uuid import uuid4    
def generate_adid(self):
        adid = str(uuid4())
        return adid
```

The failing unit test error:

`AssertionError: assert '90b29e86-e3b0-40aa-8971-f868f90cb009' == '9e51ab81-6d65-4b81-af3b-8f7f49d69ba7'`

I have consulted this post: [How to mock uuid generation in a test case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44395755/how-to-mock-uuid-generation-in-a-test-case) but still am having no luck.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks to all of those who reply in advance.

EDIT: Here is the full code:

```
from requests import Session
from random import uniform
from hashlib import md5
from hmac import new
from uuid import uuid4
from json import dumps

class AppApi:

    def __init__(self, account):
        self.account = account
        self.session = Session()

    def generate_adid(self):
        adid = str(uuid4())
        return adid
```

Test Case:

```
from src import AppApi
from pytest import fixture
from unittest.mock import patch
from json import loads


ACCOUNT = {
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "username": "user",
    "password": "s3cr3t"
}

@fixture
def app_api():
    app_api = AppApi(ACCOUNT)
    yield app_api

class TestAppApi:

    @patch('uuid.uuid4')
    def test_generate_adid(self, patched_uuid, app_api):
        patched_uuid.return_value = "9e51ab81-6d65-4b81-af3b-8f7f49d69ba7"
        adid = app_api.generate_adid()
        assert adid == "9e51ab81-6d65-4b81-af3b-8f7f49d69ba7"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you're patching the `uuid4()` function in the `uuid` module rather than the function `uuid4()` in the module which you're trying to test. Take a look at [Python unnit.test docs where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

Using your example above you need to patch the `uuid4()` imported into the `src` module. You need to use `@patch("src.uuid4")`

```py
from src import AppApi
from pytest import fixture
from unittest.mock import patch
from json import loads


ACCOUNT = {
    "email": "user@email.com",
    "username": "user",
    "password": "s3cr3t"
}

@fixture
def app_api():
    app_api = AppApi(ACCOUNT)
    yield app_api

class TestAppApi:

    @patch('src.uuid4')
    def test_generate_adid(self, patched_uuid, app_api):
        patched_uuid.return_value = "9e51ab81-6d65-4b81-af3b-8f7f49d69ba7"
        adid = app_api.generate_adid()
        assert adid == "9e51ab81-6d65-4b81-af3b-8f7f49d69ba7"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am trying to patch the `uuid4()` in the `uuid` module. With that being said this still does not solve my problem.

Comment: You must patch the function that is imported into your application code. Could you expand your example and I can try and help

Comment: I have edited the original post with the full code. Please notice that I have `AppApi` imported in `__init__.py` which is why I am able to import it directly from my `src` directory.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! To note though, I had to specify the whole path in the `@patch` decorator. So for the test to pass I needed to do the following instead: `@patch('src.app_api.uuid4')`